# non-cacheable reported in my chrome extension, how to make "cacheable"?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning to write a chrome extension. I want to inject a real-time time-stamp in current webpage.

I've already finished manifest.json, and html file as background. This html file will call a js file to get current time and display it.

While I do audits in chrome, it says:
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:clock.html, ccc.js, cbd.js.

Here are contents of these three files:

(1) clock.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="ccc.js"></script> 
</head> 
<font size="7" color='red'>
<body> 
<script src="cbd.js"></script>
<div id="showme"></div> 
</body> 
</font>
</html>
```

(2) ccc.js

```
function startTime() 
{ 
    var today=new Date(); 
    var h=today.getHours(); 
    var m=today.getMinutes() 
    var s=today.getSeconds(); 
    var w=today.getMilliseconds()%1000;

    h=checkTime(h); 
    m=checkTime(m); 
    s=checkTime(s); 
    w=checkMS(w);

    document.getElementById('showme').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+w;

    t=setTimeout('startTime()',1); 
} 

function checkTime(i) 
{ 
    if (i<10) 
    {i="0" + i;} 
        return i; 
} 
function checkMS(i) 
{ 
    if((i>9)&&(i<100))
        i="0" + i;
    else if(i<10)
        i="00" + i;
    else
        {}
    return i; 
}
```

(3)cbd.js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", startTime);
```

How to make them cacheable...?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried insert "<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=604800;private" />" into <head> of clock.html, seems not helpful.

Comment: What page are you auditing? How are you accessing that page? (`file:`, `chrome-extension:`, or `http:`? Or are you viewing the background page directly in the `chrome://extensions` page?)

Comment: In any case, I can't see how this would matter at all: there's no network activity (i.e., all the files are locally on your computer already), so there's no remote resources to cache! Where would you expect a local resource to be cached that would be any better than where it is already?

Comment: There is a link in "chrome://extension" for my extension: Insert Timestamp 1.0
Insert Timestamp
Permissions  Reload (Ctrl+R)
ID: ligmbjbbkepmogdjoodbolpjnekpefcc
Loaded from: D:\__OBSV\CCext
Inspect views: clock.html  <--------------I clicked this "clock.html" to do audits

Comment: I'm not familiar with how chrome extension works. My understanding about this extension is like this: load a local html file which can display a real-time clock, and use this html as background while I open any web pages, for example, www.google.com, then I can see both regular content of www.google.com, and at the same time, a real-time clock also "injected" into this page.....I hope this is feasible.

Comment: I understand what you said, for local files, there is no cache. For this extension, I cannot find any other problem why my extension doesn't work and display that real-time clock when I open www.google.com. Thus I tried to audit my extension and find these indication, I don't know whether this is the root course why it doesn't work...

Comment: You are _really_ looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: So the correct way is to inject only javascript into webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, problem solved.

I changed my method, just inject the java script, and it finally works.